# Openpyxl: how change row height with write_only cells and workbook

Tags: python-2.7, openpyxl

I neeed to create xls file in write-only mode and customize rows height. But rows height stay by default if i use write_only=True.

```
row = []
book = Workbook(write_only=True)
sheet = book.create_sheet()
cell_1 = WriteOnlyCell(sheet)
# styling and filling cell data
row.append(cell_1)
cell_2 = WriteOnlyCell(sheet)
# styling and filling cell data
row.append(cell_2)
sheet.append(row)
sheet.row_dimensions[len(sheet.rows)].height = 30
```

Without write_only all works perfect.

Comment: Are you trying to change the height of all the rows in the worksheet or only the height of one row?

Comment: Because [sheet.row_dimensions[len(sheet.rows)].height = 30] changes the height only of the last row.

Comment: Yep, in last row. But this code work in cycle for all rows what i append. Actually i trying to change all rows except first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Row and Column Dimensions are not available in write-only mode.

Comment: This is incorrect. It is available but must be done before any cells are added. See the warning section at the bottom of https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/optimized.html

Answer (score 4):

Must be done before any cells are added. See the warning section at the bottom of [openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/optimized.html](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/optimized.html)